# what is html element ('<element>') selector in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I was going through some jQuery lib and found html element select like `$('<img/>')` and I am really confused.

The documentation code is the following:

```
 function loadImage(src, callback) {
   $('<img />').attr('src', src).load(function() {
    TestCanvas.init(this);
    callback && callback();
    })
```

Then I tried implementing the following code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $('<img/>').attr("width", "500");
    });
});
```

didn't work as per my assumption as i assumed it as selector so what is it a selector or html element adder or what?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#creating-new-elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

passing an element string as in `$('<img />')` will actually create an html element within a jquery wrapper.

You can manipulate this in memory like you would a DOM element.

When you are ready to use this element, you could add it to the DOM using jQuery functions such as append() or prepend().

Comment: I upvoted your answer for being correct, but I feel like it might be a bit too havyhanded for OP in question to understand. **In layman's terms, if you put the an element inside the "html" tags of your jQuery selector, it will try to create an html element - tag -  instead of selecting one.** < This is not the exactly correct definition, but probably most beginner friendly way to explain it.

Answer (score 2):

If first example you are using, [`jQuery(html)`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2) which

> Creates DOM elements on the fly from the provided string of raw HTML.

`$('<img />')` will create a DOM object for `IMG` tag, Here is an example to create HTML

```js
//Create a new DOM object/element
var img = $('<img/>'); 

//Mainpuate properties
img.prop("src", "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-ieBdk590MHM/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAACI/-D_w2n30j4I/photo.jpg?sz=328"); 

//Append to DIV
img.appendTo('div');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

If you intent to create select element, use [Element Selector (“element”)](https://api.jquery.com/element-selector/)

```js
$('img').width(100);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-ieBdk590MHM/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAACI/-D_w2n30j4I/photo.jpg?sz=328">
</div>
```

Comment: objects? where would we use that object, i still don't get it, explain or give some links please, thank you.